# How to check some certain condition before insert operation

Tags: php, mysql

I have two variables which return array output and here is the example.

**$scheduleRrecords:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [scheduleId] => 1
            [ownerId] => 32
            [userId] => 33
            [scheduleCategoryId] => 53
            [shiftTimeId] => 8
            [dayPartId] => 34
            [shiftBreakId] => 3
            [colorCodeId] => 1
            [scheduleDate] => 2017-01-02
            [startTime] => 20:00:00
            [endTime] => 22:00:00
            [shiftNote] => Sidecar Swing
            [scheduleNote] => 
            [alert] => 0
            [scheduleDay] => Monday
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [scheduleId] => 2
            [ownerId] => 32
            [userId] => 33
            [scheduleCategoryId] => 53
            [shiftTimeId] => 7
            [dayPartId] => 33
            [shiftBreakId] => 2
            [colorCodeId] => 2
            [scheduleDate] => 2017-01-02
            [startTime] => 10:00:00
            [endTime] => 13:00:00
            [shiftNote] => Mid
            [scheduleNote] => 
            [alert] => 0
            [scheduleDay] => Monday
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [scheduleId] => 3
            [ownerId] => 32
            [userId] => 33
            [scheduleCategoryId] => 53
            [shiftTimeId] => 8
            [dayPartId] => 34
            [shiftBreakId] => 3
            [colorCodeId] => 1
            [scheduleDate] => 2017-01-03
            [startTime] => 20:00:00
            [endTime] => 22:00:00
            [shiftNote] => Sidecar Swing
            [scheduleNote] => 
            [alert] => 0
            [scheduleDay] => Tuesday
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [scheduleId] => 4
            [ownerId] => 32
            [userId] => 33
            [scheduleCategoryId] => 53
            [shiftTimeId] => 7
            [dayPartId] => 33
            [shiftBreakId] => 3
            [colorCodeId] => 2
            [scheduleDate] => 2017-01-03
            [startTime] => 10:00:00
            [endTime] => 13:00:00
            [shiftNote] => Mid
            [scheduleNote] => 
            [alert] => 0
            [scheduleDay] => Tuesday
        )

)
```

**$checkRequestOffObj:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [requestOffId] => 4
            [ownerId] => 32
            [userId] => 33
            [requestOffDate] => 2017-01-09
            [dayPartId] => 33
            [isPermRequest] => no
            [requestOffNote] => 
            [permNote] => 
            [requestStatus] => pending
            [approvedOrDeclinedBy] => 
            [approvedOrDeclinedNote] => 
            [firstName] => Erick
            [lastName] => Venere
            [email] => erick.portalic@gmail.com
            [dayPartName] => Lunch
            [status] => 1
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [requestOffId] => 5
            [ownerId] => 32
            [userId] => 33
            [requestOffDate] => 2017-01-10
            [dayPartId] => 33
            [isPermRequest] => yes
            [requestOffNote] => 
            [permNote] => 
            [requestStatus] => pending
            [approvedOrDeclinedBy] => 
            [approvedOrDeclinedNote] => 
            [firstName] => Erick
            [lastName] => Venere
            [email] => erick.portalic@gmail.com
            [dayPartName] => Lunch
            [status] => 1
        )

)
```

Now I don't want to insert records into the database with this condition:

1. If `[isPermRequest] => no` then don't insert records to that `[requestOffDate] => 2017-01-09` date.
2. If `[isPermRequest] => yes` then check `[requestOffDate] => 2017-01-09` day. Let's say `2017-01-09` is `Monday` so don't insert records to all `Monday`.

I have one main `for loop` which is used for `$scheduleRrecords` to loop the data and checking isPermRequest inside this loop.

**Here is my core logic:**

```
if (!empty($scheduleRrecords)) {
    for ($a=0; $a<count($scheduleRrecords); $a++) {
        if (isset($scheduleRrecords[$a]->ownerId) && !empty($scheduleRrecords[$a]->ownerId)) {
            $aOwnerId = $scheduleRrecords[$a]->ownerId;
        } else {
            $aOwnerId = "";
        }

        if (isset($scheduleRrecords[$a]->userId) && !empty($scheduleRrecords[$a]->userId)) {
            $aUserId = $scheduleRrecords[$a]->userId;
        } else {
            $aUserId = "";
        }

        if (isset($scheduleRrecords[$a]->scheduleCategoryId) && !empty($scheduleRrecords[$a]->scheduleCategoryId)) {
            $aScheduleCategoryId = $scheduleRrecords[$a]->scheduleCategoryId;
        } else {
            $aScheduleCategoryId = "";
        }

        if (isset($scheduleRrecords[$a]->shiftTimeId) && !empty($scheduleRrecords[$a]->shiftTimeId)) {
            $aShiftTimeId = $scheduleRrecords[$a]->shiftTimeId;
        } else {
            $aShiftTimeId = "";
        }

        if (isset($scheduleRrecords[$a]->dayPartId) && !empty($scheduleRrecords[$a]->dayPartId)) {
            $aDayPartId = $scheduleRrecords[$a]->dayPartId;
        } else {
            $aDayPartId = "";
        }

        if (isset($scheduleRrecords[$a]->shiftBreakId) && !empty($scheduleRrecords[$a]->shiftBreakId)) {
            $aShiftBreakId = $scheduleRrecords[$a]->shiftBreakId;
        } else {
            $aShiftBreakId = "";
        }

        if (isset($scheduleRrecords[$a]->colorCodeId) && !empty($scheduleRrecords[$a]->colorCodeId)) {
            $aColorCodeId = $scheduleRrecords[$a]->colorCodeId;
        } else {
            $aColorCodeId = "";
        }

        if (isset($scheduleRrecords[$a]->scheduleDate) && !empty($scheduleRrecords[$a]->scheduleDate)) {
            $aScheduleDate = $scheduleRrecords[$a]->scheduleDate;
        } else {
            $aScheduleDate = "";
        }

        if (isset($scheduleRrecords[$a]->startTime) && !empty($scheduleRrecords[$a]->startTime)) {
            $aStartTime = $scheduleRrecords[$a]->startTime;
        } else {
            $aStartTime = "";
        }

        if (isset($scheduleRrecords[$a]->endTime) && !empty($scheduleRrecords[$a]->endTime)) {
            $aEndTime = $scheduleRrecords[$a]->endTime;
        } else {
            $aEndTime = "";
        }

        if (isset($scheduleRrecords[$a]->shiftNote) && !empty($scheduleRrecords[$a]->shiftNote)) {
            $aShiftNote = $scheduleRrecords[$a]->shiftNote;
        } else {
            $aShiftNote = "";
        }

        if (isset($scheduleRrecords[$a]->scheduleNote) && !empty($scheduleRrecords[$a]->scheduleNote)) {
            $aScheduleNote = $scheduleRrecords[$a]->scheduleNote;
        } else {
            $aScheduleNote = "";
        }

        // Get next week date from scheduleDate
        $getUserNextWeekArr = GlobalHelper::getUserNextWeek($aOwnerId, $aScheduleDate);
        $nextDate = $getUserNextWeekArr['next'];

        // Get weekly date array from selected start date
        $getOwnerWeekListArr = GlobalHelper::getOwnerWeekList($aOwnerId, $copyStartDate);

        // Get scheduleDate day name
        $dayOfWeek = date('D', strtotime($aScheduleDate));

        // Obtain The Key Of The Array
        $nextDate = "";
        foreach ($getOwnerWeekListArr as $key => $val) {
            if ($val['day'] == $dayOfWeek) {
                $nextDate .= $getOwnerWeekListArr[$key]['date'];
            }
        }

        $scheduleDate = str_replace('/', '-', date('Y-m-d', strtotime($nextDate)));

        $checkRequestOffObj = GlobalHelper::checkRequestOff($aOwnerId, $aUserId, $aDayPartId, $scheduleDate);
    }
}
```

**Here is my login but it's not working:**

```
if (!empty($checkRequestOffObj)) {
    for ($t=0; $t<count($checkRequestOffObj); $t++) {
        $tRequestOffDate = $checkRequestOffObj[$t]->requestOffDate;
        $tRequestOffDay = date('D', strtotime($checkRequestOffObj[$t]->requestOffDate));
        $tDayPartId = $checkRequestOffObj[$t]->dayPartId;

        if ($checkRequestOffObj[$t]->isPermRequest == 'yes') {
            if ($dayOfWeek == $tRequestOffDay && $aDayPartId != $tDayPartId) {
                $result = DB::table('schedules')
                    ->where('ownerId', '=', $aOwnerId)
                    ->where('userId', '=', $aUserId)
                    ->where('scheduleCategoryId', '=', $aScheduleCategoryId)
                    ->where('shiftTimeId', '=', $aShiftTimeId)
                    ->where('dayPartId', '=', $aDayPartId)
                    ->where('shiftBreakId', '=', $aShiftBreakId)
                    ->where('colorCodeId', '=', $aColorCodeId)
                    ->where('scheduleDate', '=', $scheduleDate)
                    ->exists();

                if ($result == ""):
                    DB::table('schedules')->insert(
                        array(
                            'ownerId' => $aOwnerId,
                            'userId' => $aUserId,
                            'scheduleCategoryId' => $aScheduleCategoryId,
                            'shiftTimeId' => $aShiftTimeId,
                            'dayPartId' => $aDayPartId,
                            'shiftBreakId' => $aShiftBreakId,
                            'colorCodeId' => $aColorCodeId,
                            'scheduleDate' => $scheduleDate,
                            'startTime' => $aStartTime,
                            'endTime' => $aEndTime,
                            'shiftNote' => $aShiftNote,
                            'scheduleNote' => $aScheduleNote,
                            'createdBy' => Auth::user()->userId,
                            'isPosted' => "0",
                            'sendSchedule' => "0",
                            'cronStatus' => "0",
                        )
                    );
                endif;
            } else {
                continue;
            }
        } else {
            if ($aDayPartId != $tDayPartId && $scheduleDate == $tRequestOffDate) {
                $result = DB::table('schedules')
                    ->where('ownerId', '=', $aOwnerId)
                    ->where('userId', '=', $aUserId)
                    ->where('scheduleCategoryId', '=', $aScheduleCategoryId)
                    ->where('shiftTimeId', '=', $aShiftTimeId)
                    ->where('dayPartId', '=', $aDayPartId)
                    ->where('shiftBreakId', '=', $aShiftBreakId)
                    ->where('colorCodeId', '=', $aColorCodeId)
                    ->where('scheduleDate', '=', $scheduleDate)
                    ->exists();

                if ($result == ""):
                    DB::table('schedules')->insert(
                        array(
                            'ownerId' => $aOwnerId,
                            'userId' => $aUserId,
                            'scheduleCategoryId' => $aScheduleCategoryId,
                            'shiftTimeId' => $aShiftTimeId,
                            'dayPartId' => $aDayPartId,
                            'shiftBreakId' => $aShiftBreakId,
                            'colorCodeId' => $aColorCodeId,
                            'scheduleDate' => $scheduleDate,
                            'startTime' => $aStartTime,
                            'endTime' => $aEndTime,
                            'shiftNote' => $aShiftNote,
                            'scheduleNote' => $aScheduleNote,
                            'createdBy' => Auth::user()->userId,
                            'isPosted' => "0",
                            'sendSchedule' => "0",
                            'cronStatus' => "0",
                        )
                    );
                endif;
            } else {
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
} else {

}
```

Any Idea how to check before insert operation?

Thanks.

Comment: You can check your condition with a normal if condition and skip the current for-loop with _continue_

Comment: Can you please guide me how to do that because I am trying from last 6 hours but it is not working for me.

Comment: Where in the for-loop is your data stored in the database? Is ` GlobalHelper::checkRequestOff()` doing this?

Comment: `GlobalHelper::checkRequestOff()` return `$checkRequestOffObj` variable array.  Yes that is coming from database.

Comment: @DennisKoch I updated my question and added logic.

Comment: Can you explain your conditions a little bit more?
1) You want to skip all records that have a date defined in $checkRequestOffObj 2) You want to skip all records with the same weekday as the records in $checkRequestOffObj: ?